# how to ignore builtin xslt rules

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lib>
    <books xmlns="http://www.books.com/SRK">
        <name>English</name>
    </books>
    <cats>
        <cat>cat1</cat>
        <cat>cat2</cat>
    </cats>
</lib>
```

and this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="//cats/*">        
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the expected out is to not have english in output but first it  write english and then what I need.
I mean currently output is :

```
English<cat>cat1</cat>
<cat>cat2</cat>
```

but I don't want it contain English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply your template only to `cats` section. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">                       
           <xsl:apply-templates select="//cats"/>                  
    </xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="cats">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```